# hashCode values not same in debugger and output in netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Naveen", 100);
    System.out.println("Naveen".hashCode());
    /* output (-1968696341) so index=(-1968696341&15)=11
    but in netbeans 8.2 and jdk 1.8 debugger hashcode = -1968662205
    so the index=(-1968662205&15)=3
     */
```

where is the problem my enviornment is
netbeans 8.2 jdk 1.8

Comment: It works for me.  I see the same hashcode in the debugger as gets printed on the screen.  I think you may be interpreting your debugger output incorrectly.  Try `int hash = "Naveen".hashCode();` look at the code with a debugger, you should see the correct value.

Comment: @markspace i tried int hash = "Naveen".hashCode(); but igot the same result

Comment: @user16320675 String's hashCode is [specified](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) to be repeatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual hashCode of the string `"Naveen"` is indeed -1968696341, and it must always be so by [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) (despite comments to the contrary).

The `HashMap` implementation doesn't use the key's hashCode value directly. Instead, it "spreads" the bits using the formula `h ^ (h >>> 16)` in order to use the high-order bits to help reduce collisions. If you apply this formula to the string's hashCode, the result is -1968662205 which matches what you see in the debugger.

The JDK 8 code for this is [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L320), along with an explanation in a comment, quoted here for convenience.

```
    /**
     * Computes key.hashCode() and spreads (XORs) higher bits of hash
     * to lower.  Because the table uses power-of-two masking, sets of
     * hashes that vary only in bits above the current mask will
     * always collide. (Among known examples are sets of Float keys
     * holding consecutive whole numbers in small tables.)  So we
     * apply a transform that spreads the impact of higher bits
     * downward. There is a tradeoff between speed, utility, and
     * quality of bit-spreading. Because many common sets of hashes
     * are already reasonably distributed (so don't benefit from
     * spreading), and because we use trees to handle large sets of
     * collisions in bins, we just XOR some shifted bits in the
     * cheapest possible way to reduce systematic lossage, as well as
     * to incorporate impact of the highest bits that would otherwise
     * never be used in index calculations because of table bounds.
     */
    static final int hash(Object key) {
        int h;
        return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
    }
```